# How to store a random number in several variables?

Tags: python

How do I store a random number into several variables?

So far I have this:

```
import random
random_selection = random.random()
random_number_1 = random_selection
print(random_number_1)
```

Now when I run random_selection again, it stores a new number into random_number_1

I do not want this. I want random_number_1 to store the initial random number, and then when I run random_selection again, I want to be able to store this new random number into another variable called random_number_2

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, at the very least you'll need to mention `random_number_2` *somewhere* in the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "run" `random_selection`?  `random_selection` is just a variable; it cannot be "run".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "run `random_selection`". It is not a function or any other callable, but a `float`:

```
import random
random_number_1 = random.random()
random_number_2 = random.random()
```

You have to call the `random()` function again in order to get a new random number. For multiple random numbers, I recommend you to use a list, which you can create with a comprehension:

```
# list of 5 random numbers
random_numbers = [random.random() for _ in xrange(5)]
```

If you don't like a list, but want to keep individual variables, you can use multiple assignment:

```
a, b, c = (random.random() for _ in xrange(3))
```

Comment: How would I assign several random numbers to different variables in one swoop, without having to call random.random() every time?

Comment: @EdwardK.: Every time you want a new random number, you have to call `random.random` again.  It just returns one random number.  If you want to get multiple random numbers, you could look at using some of the random function in numpy.  But that still won't give you a random number just by accessing a variable; you have to call a function.

Comment: If a variable contains a function, does the variable itself not become the function, hence being able to run the variable in place of the function?

Comment: @EdwardK. You can store the function to a variable like: `fnc=random.random` (notice the missing parentheses), but then you still have to call `fnc` via `fnc()`. What you do in your code is store the return value of the function to a variable, not the function itself.

Comment: @EdwardK.: It can work that way, yes.  But you're not storing the function, you're storing its return value.  Also, even if you store the function, you still have to call it (via the variable) later.